# C# Max Value of a Column in Data Table

Tags: c#

I am trying to take the maximum value of a column(especially the first) in data table , here is my code :

```
TableData  tableData = ReadTableData(Body.GetEx<string>(JsonKeys.Engine_O2Map), "O2Map");
double max_enginespeed_fc;
max_enginespeed_fc = FuelConsumptionMap.Compute(
    ("MAX([" + (FuelConsumptionMap.Columns[0].ColumnName + "])")), "");
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in tableData.Rows)
{
    row[0] = 0;
}

return tableData;
```

But I take the following error :

> Error  CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'double'. An    explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

FuelConsumption Map is another datatable that exists in program.

The problem is with the `max_enginespeed_fc`.

What should I do to correct this ?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

---

Comment: FuelConsumptionMap.Columns[0].ColumnName. Check the type. It is probably not double

Comment: What is `TableData`?

Comment: *Where* do you get that error?

Comment: Probably just `max_enginespeed_fc = (double) FuelConsumptionMap`?

Comment: Does a casting here solve the problem? `max_enginespeed_fc = (double)FuelConsumptionMap.Compute(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The [DataTable.Compute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTable_Compute_System_String_System_String_) method returns an *object* that you have to cast to the correct type before using it.

The error explains what's wrong. The way the code is written though, it's hard to understand which statement causes it. This:

```
double max_enginespeed_fc;
max_enginespeed_fc = FuelConsumptionMap.Compute(
("MAX([" + (FuelConsumptionMap.Columns[0].ColumnName + "])")), "");
```

Should be rewritten as :

```
var column = FuelConsumptionMap.Columns[0].ColumnName;
var expression=String.Format("MAX([{0}])",column);
double max_enginespeed_fc;
max_enginespeed_fc = FuelConsumptionMap.Compute(expression, "");
```

This would make it clear that the problem is the return value of `Compute`. To get the result as a `double` requires a single cast :

```
var column = FuelConsumptionMap.Columns[0].ColumnName;
var expression=String.Format("MAX([{0}])",column);
var max_enginespeed_fc = (double)FuelConsumptionMap.Compute(expression, "");
```

Using string interpolation this can become :

```
var column = FuelConsumptionMap.Columns[0].ColumnName;
var expression=$"MAX([{column}])";
var max_enginespeed_fc = (double)FuelConsumptionMap.Compute(expression, "");
```

Or even

```
var column = FuelConsumptionMap.Columns[0].ColumnName;
var max_enginespeed_fc = (double)FuelConsumptionMap.Compute($"MAX([{column}])", "");
```